# sObject type 'CronTrigger' is not supported in PostInstallScript

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, package-install, postinstall

In my PostInstallScript I want to delete a Cron job but I got this error :

> The pull upgrade of your package failed. Here are the details:
>
> Error Message: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: sObject
> type 'CronTrigger'     is not supported.

here is part of my code :

```
global without sharing class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        if (context.previousVersion() == null) {
            // Fresh install - nothing to do
        } else {
            if(context.previousVersion().compareTo(new Version(1,9)) <= 0) {
                String jobName = 'jobname';
                List<CronTrigger> cronJobs = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name LIKE :jobName];
                if (cronJobs.size() != 0) {
                    System.debug('Deleting job '+cronJobs[0].Id+' for "'+jobName+'"');
                    System.abortJob(cronJobs[0].Id);
                }
```

Comment: While we do not try to delete, we have installer code that queries like `if ([SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = '...` and inserts new if required. Not sure exactly what could be wrong since this should be running as the package ghost user and that should have permissions. What type of org are you installing to, and did your installer for earlier version insert the relevant scheduled job?

Comment: This has to be new, we have code like this that we ran some time ago  but as that old version has never been around I doubt it gets executed much anymore.

Answer (score 0):

we fix the issue . the issue was that we define our PostInstallScript `global without sharing` and we had a method that contains that CronTrigger and that method was in a class with `global with sharing` . so we remove the with sharing of that class and everything works fine.